# How to add a new column to a dataframe in condition on the previous row of the desired value to be all NAs?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, multiple-columns

I have this dataframe df and the vector z

```
df = data.frame(x =c(letters[1:3],NA,NA,'part1',letters[4:5],NA,NA,'part2',
letters[6:7]),
                y = c('p1','p2','p3',NA,NA,'---','p4',
'p5',NA,NA,'---','p6','p7') )


z = 5:6
```

and I want to create a column the is called `score` with part1 has the score 5 and part2 has the score 6. the condition is that the row before each **part** is composed of NAs. The other values in the score column would be NAs. Appreciate the help.

the expected output

```
       x    y   score
1      a   p1    NA
2      b   p2    NA
3      c   p3    NA
4   <NA> <NA>    NA
5   <NA> <NA>    NA
6  part1  ---    5
7      d   p4    NA
8      e   p5    NA
9   <NA> <NA>    NA
10  <NA> <NA>    NA
11 part2  ---    6
12     f   p6    NA
13     g   p7    NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will apply the values in `z` to the rows of `df` where `x` contains 'part':

```
df$score[grepl('part', df$x)] <- z
```

Answer (score 1):

I would redefine `z` as a named vector then you can do the following safely:

```
z = c("part1" = 5, "part2" = 6)
df$score = z[df$x]

#        x    y score
# 1      a   p1    NA
# 2      b   p2    NA
# 3      c   p3    NA
# 4   <NA> <NA>    NA
# 5   <NA> <NA>    NA
# 6  part1  ---     5
# 7      d   p4    NA
# 8      e   p5    NA
# 9   <NA> <NA>    NA
# 10  <NA> <NA>    NA
# 11 part2  ---     6
# 12     f   p6    NA
# 13     g   p7    NA
```